# Whats the use of values in enum in Python?

Tags: python, enums

I'm working with `enum` lately and I dont really get the utility of them in some cases. I hope my question is not too trivial or too stupid, and I would really love to better understand the logic behind this python structure. One common use I found online or in some pieces of code I have been working on lately is the use of `values` that are strings like for example:

```
from enum import Enum

class Days(Enum):
    MONDAY = 'monday'
    TUESDAY = 'tuesday'
    ...
    SUNDAY = 'sunday'
```

And here from my humble prospective, the values seems redundant: if I print the values of some member I obtain the following:

```
print(Days.MONDAY.value)
>> 'monday'
```

I totally understand the utility when the values are numbers and they represent a  gerarchic structure like for example

```
class Levels(Enum):
    HIGH = 10
    MID = 5
    LOW = 0
```

In which you can do stuff like:

```
HIGH > LOW
> True
```

But in a lot of example and actual code use, I see the first approach, the one with `MONDAY = 'monday'`, i.e. when the values are string instead of numerical values, and this case I really dont understand the utility of having a key that is pretty much equal to the value.

If anyone can help me understand, or show some utilities I would really love to understand new stuff.

Comment: For one thing, just because the enum name happens to *currently* match its value, that doesn't mean that must always be the case.  You could come in later and refactor the `Days` enum to instead use `MON`, `TUE`, `WED`, etc, without breaking any code that relies on the string values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members (should) always be named in all uppercase (per the very first note on [the `enum` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum)), so if you want them to have "names" that are in some other casing, you can assign strings with arbitrary case, which may be more human-friendly when it comes time to display the values to the user.

You can also convert from said values to the `enum` constant easily, with the `Enum`'s constructor, e.g.:

```
Days('monday') is Days.MONDAY  # This is True
```

so if the data from the user (or database or whatever) has specific values, you can easily convert them to their logical `Enum` equivalents this way.

If the values really aren't meaningful, you can just [assign `auto()` to all of them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values) and not think about the values.

Just in case you're asking "why not use the strings themselves?", the general advantage to `enum`s is guaranteed uniqueness and exhaustiveness for efficient checks and self-documenting code. If you use the strings directly, you have to use `==` checks (`str` has no guarantee that equal values are the same object unless you explicitly `intern` them, so `is` checks can't be used), and people can pass in strings that don't actually come from the expected set of strings. With `Enum`s there is a central definition of all possible values (and therefore all other values are not possible), and since the values are all guaranteed singletons, when you have a member of that `Enum`, you can use `is`/`is not` testing for cheap identity testing (in CPython at least, it's literally just a pointer comparison) without relying on value equality tests, `==`/`!=`, that invoke the more expensive rich comparison machinery. This even works when you make aliases for the same enum member, e.g.:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    SPAM = 1
    EGGS = 2
    ALSO_SPAM = 1
```

which seamlessly makes `Foo.ALSO_SPAM` the same object as `Foo.SPAM` so `Foo.SPAM is Foo.ALSO_SPAM` is true, allowing two aliases with different names to be used interchangably.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the answer I was looking for, in particular the "why not use the strings themselves?" part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's one approach to adding type safety to your code. Even if `Days` *looks* like a collection of strings, it's not a subclass/subtype/special-case of `str`.

```
>>> isinstance(Days.MONDAY, Days)
True
>>> isinstance('monday', Days)
False
>>> isinstance(Days.MONDAY, str)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ShadowRanger's answer:  The primary reason why `Enum` has both a `name` and a `value` field is so meaningful constants can have easy to use names -- constants such as database values, various codes (http, error, response, etc.) -- in other words, so `Enum` can provide an easy interface with other systems.